# Upgrade Orbeon 3.9 to 4.5

Tags: orbeon

We are upgrading Orbeon 3.9 to 4.5.
And we are using MySQL 6.1 and JBOSS 5.1.

Followed the procedures described in http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers?pli=1 for upgrade.

I am getting the Form Runner Home just fine (showing the old applications and forms).

And also If I open any new form(which I created after upgrade) from form runner, its perfect, no problem. 
But When I try to click on any old form , I am getting error "An error has occurred in Orbeon Forms"

And In Orbeon.log file, I can see the following :

2014-05-08 14:38:40,151 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  - error caught {controller: "oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml", method: "GET", path: "/fr/ApplicationName/formName/edit/5273bf03-9f0a-4ab9-b441-94c1dcdffad2"}
2014-05-08 14:38:40,274 ERROR PageFlowControllerProcessor  - 
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

|An Error has Occurred                                                                                                 |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|XPath syntax error at char 0 in {}:                                                                                   |
|    Unexpected token **<"eof">** in path expression
                                                              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|Application Call Stack                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/apps/fr/page-flow.xml                                                        |executing processor           | 208|
|······················································································································|
|name={http://www.orbeon.com/oxf/processors}pipeline                                                                   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/config/epilogue.xpl                                                          |executing processor           |  60|
|······················································································································|
|element=[...]                                                          |
|name   ={}pipeline                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/config/epilogue-servlet.xpl                                                  |reading processor output      |  31|
|······················································································································|
|element=                                                                   |
|name   =xformed-data                                                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/config/epilogue.xpl                                                          |reading processor output      |  41|
|······················································································································|
|element=                                                             |
|name   =xformed-data                                                                                                  |
|id     =xformed-data                                                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-epilogue.xpl                                                  |reading processor output      |  95|
|······················································································································|
|element=                                                                    |
|name   =data                                                                                                          |
|ref    =xformed-data                                                                                                  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-epilogue.xpl                                                  |reading processor output      |  88|
|······················································································································|
|element=                                                                   |
|name   =data                                                                                                          |
|id     =xincluded-data                                                                                                |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|oxf:/ops/pfc/xforms-epilogue.xpl                                                  |reading processor output      |  77|
|······················································································································|
|element=                                                                   |
|name   =document                                                                                                      |
|id     =xhtml-data                                                                                                    |

Comment: Can you provide an example of a form which fails? You can do so privately at info at orbeon dot com if the form is not public.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have sent the example form to info at orbeon dot com. Please have a look on it and help me to solve this issue